# Randomly choosing an equation and answer from a list - PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a math game where it randomly chooses a question from my list and gives the corresponding answer. At the moment, I can get the questions to randomise however, it gives the answer in order from the list, not the answer corresponding to the question.
How do I get the answer to be correct to the random question.
Here is my code.

```
import random

counter = 0
score = 0
incorrect = 0

name=input("What is your name?")
print("Hi",name,",welcome to your math quiz!")

questions = ["10*2","4-2","6+12","6*4","12-5","6+54","1*0","3-6","4+0","65-9"]
answers=["20","2","18","24",'7','60','0','-3','4','56']

idx_questions = list(enumerate(questions))
idx_answers = list(enumerate(answers))

random.shuffle(idx_questions)

for idxq, question in idx_questions:
    print(question)
    ans = input("What is the answer? ")
    for idxa, answer in idx_answers:
        if idxq == idxa and ans == answer:
            print("Correct")
            score=score+1
            print("Correct Answers=",score)
            print("Incorrect Answers=",incorrect)

        elif idxq == idxa and ans != answer:
            print("Incorrect", answers)
            incorrect=incorrect+1
            print("Correct Answers=",score)
            print("Incorrect Answers=",incorrect)

print("End of quiz")
print(name,"your score is",score,"out of 10")
print(score*10,"%")
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add the actual code, instead of linking a screenshot. This helps users reading and understanding your code, and allows copying it for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random

counter = 0
score = 0
incorrect = 0

questions = ["10*2","4-2","6+12","6*4"]
answers=["20","2","18","24"]

idx_questions = list(enumerate(questions))
idx_answers = list(enumerate(answers))

random.shuffle(idx_questions)

for idxq, question in idx_questions:
    print(question)
    ans = input("What is the answer? ")
    for idxa, answer in idx_answers:
        if idxq == idxa and ans == answer:
            print("Correct")
        elif idxq == idxa and ans != answer:
            print("Incorrect")
```

Comment: Can you please explain further how to do this? I am new to python

Comment: Thank you! That actually works perfectly. my issue now is that when the answer is incorrect, I want to display the correct answer. However at the moment, it displays the whole list of answers. Do you have any suggestions? I have added in my current code to my question

Comment: @Jane just print in the second if the answer (without the s) variable. Please if you think that I helped you upvote the comment and, if you think that I solved your question mark it as the correct answer

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you shuffle question list, while answers list stays the same. So now answers and questions, have a diffrent position and they doesn't match. Instead you should just generate random index and print question at that index.

```
random_int = random.randint(0, len(questions)-1)
print(question[random_int])
```

Of course you should build some mechanism to prevent the same answer to pop twice. One way is removing used questions.

```
del questions[random_int]
del answers[random_int]
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you. Only problem I am having is that the list index is out of range after 9 questions, even though i have my counter at 10 and random.randint at (0,10)

Comment: There is no index 10 if your list is len == 10. It is from 0 to 9. So your random.randint should be (0,9) also if you delete used answer it igets lower and lower.